# Ruby code forces the answer using a loop and a branch to guess my favorite ice cream flavor

Tags: beginner, ruby

I'm writing very simple programs. "Crawl before you walk..." they say.

How could I clean this up? And/or simplify?

While I am very new, technical lanquage is necessary because it helps me learn the lessons I need to learn

```
puts "What is my favorite ice cream flavor?"

ice_cream_1 = gets.chomp.capitalize

while ice_cream_1 != "Vanilla"
   puts "Wrong answer; what is my favorite ice cream flavor?"

   my_favorite_ice_cream_flavor = gets.chomp.capitalize

   if my_favorite_ice_cream_flavor == "Vanilla"
      break
   end
end

puts "Now that's my jam"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to write the `gets` and the string comparison code twice. The following code is equivalent:

```
puts "What is my favorite ice cream flavor?"
while gets.chomp.capitalize != "Vanilla"
   puts "Wrong answer; what is my favorite ice cream flavor?"
end
puts "Now that's my jam"
```